# Duality between 'Eigenvalues ​of Laplace Operators' and 'Length of Closed Geodesic'.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Could anyone tell me an introductory reference on the duality between 'Eigenvalues ​​of Laplace Operators' and 'Length of Closed Geodesic'?

My curiosity to know this duality came from an answer in Mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/89675/36917).